# Is it possible to get information like Tempo from a .CAF file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am developing an Audio Application.

I have a set of .caf files of Apple logic Pro.
I would want to extract in information like tempo and if possible other audio data.

I am very less experienced in Audio applications but got some knowledge in audio though.

Any sample code would really be appreciated.

Somebody please save me!!

Thank you

Comment: Analyze the audio.  Generally involves using fast Fourier transform.  You may get some help on the Signal Processing SO site.